# Conversion in .net: Native Utf-8 <-> Managed String

Tags: c#, string, utf-8, marshalling, native

I created those two methods to convert Native utf-8 strings (char*) into managed string and vice versa. The following code does the job:

```
public IntPtr NativeUtf8FromString(string managedString)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(managedString); // not null terminated
    Array.Resize(ref buffer, buffer.Length + 1);
    buffer[buffer.Length - 1] = 0; // terminating 0
    IntPtr nativeUtf8 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffer.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, nativeUtf8, buffer.Length);
    return nativeUtf8;
}

string StringFromNativeUtf8(IntPtr nativeUtf8)
{
    int size = 0;
    byte[] buffer = {};
    do
    {
        ++size;
        Array.Resize(ref buffer, size);
        Marshal.Copy(nativeUtf8, buffer, 0, size);
    } while (buffer[size - 1] != 0); // till 0 termination found

    if (1 == size)
    {
        return ""; // empty string
    }

    Array.Resize(ref buffer, size - 1); // remove terminating 0
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
}
```

While NativeUtf8FromString is ok, StringFromNativeUtf8 is a mess but the only safe code I could get to run. Using unsafe code I could use an byte* but I do not want unsafe code. Is there another way someone can think of where I do not have to copy the string for every contained byte to find the 0 termination.

---

I just add the unsave code here:

```
public unsafe string StringFromNativeUtf8(IntPtr nativeUtf8)
{
    byte* bytes = (byte*)nativeUtf8.ToPointer();
    int size = 0;
    while (bytes[size] != 0)
    {
        ++size;
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)nativeUtf8, buffer, 0, size);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
}
```

As you see its not ugly just needs unsafe.

Comment: Why do you care about not using `unsafe` code?

Comment: @CodelnChaos: Not sure. Because Procect has to activate the /unsafe switch which feels dirty to me.

Comment: The `/unsafe` switch is pretty meaningless. `Marshal.*` is just as unsafe as pointer code, even if it doesn't require the switch.

Comment: @CodelnChaos: I totally agree that marshalling is as unsafe as the pointer code but I thought its worth a question. Maybe there is an easy soluton that I just didn't find.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Surely /unsafe means you can break the CLR, and Marshal won't let you do that?

Comment: @david.pfx `Marshal.Copy` allows you to write data to arbitrary memory locations, just like pointers allow you to write data to arbitrary memory locations. No difference in the damage you can do.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: there is a lot of difference, which is why one is unsafe and the other is not. This is not the place to debate -- ask a question if you like.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just perform the exact same operation strlen() performs.  Do consider keeping the *buffer* around, the code does generate garbage in a hurry.

```
    public static IntPtr NativeUtf8FromString(string managedString) {
        int len = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(managedString);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len + 1];
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(managedString, 0, managedString.Length, buffer, 0);
        IntPtr nativeUtf8 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffer.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, nativeUtf8, buffer.Length);
        return nativeUtf8;
    }

    public static string StringFromNativeUtf8(IntPtr nativeUtf8) {
        int len = 0;
        while (Marshal.ReadByte(nativeUtf8, len) != 0) ++len;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        Marshal.Copy(nativeUtf8, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    }
```

Comment: byte[] buffer = new byte[len - 1];

should be 
byte[] buffer = new byte[len];

Comment: But your code includes to len all up to (but not including) to null terminator. So len contains the amount of characters without null terminator.

Comment: I could have sworn I tested this.  Off-by-one bugs suck.  Thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant: Docs say that Encoding.UTF8 inserts a BOM. Is that not a problem here?

Answer (score 10):

Slightly faster than Hans' solution (1 less buffer copy):

```
private unsafe IntPtr AllocConvertManagedStringToNativeUtf8(string input) {
    fixed (char* pInput = input) {
        var len = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(pInput, input.Length);
        var pResult = (byte*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len + 1).ToPointer();
        var bytesWritten = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pInput, input.Length, pResult, len);
        Trace.Assert(len == bytesWritten);
        pResult[len] = 0;
        return (IntPtr)pResult;
    }
}

private unsafe string MarshalNativeUtf8ToManagedString(IntPtr pStringUtf8)
    => MarshalNativeUtf8ToManagedString((byte*)pStringUtf8);

private unsafe string MarshalNativeUtf8ToManagedString(byte* pStringUtf8) {
    var len = 0;
    while (pStringUtf8[len] != 0) len++;
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pStringUtf8, len);
}
```

Here's I demo round-tripping a string:

```
var input = "Hello, World!";
var native = AllocConvertManagedStringToNativeUtf8(input);
var copy = MarshalNativeUtf8ToManagedString(native);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(native); // don't leak unmanaged memory!
Trace.Assert(input == copy); // prove they're equal!
```

Comment: Assuming that you have a valid Unicode string as `input`, then the `Assert` on `len == bytesWritten` would never fail, correct? If that's true then you could make this a fair amount faster by over-allocating using `input.Length * 4 + 1` bytes. `GetBytes` will tell you the actual byte length without having to parse the entire string twice (`GetByteCount` and then `GetBytes`).

Answer (score 9):

[Marshal.PtrToStringUTF8](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringutf8) and [Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUTF8](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtocotaskmemutf8) were added in .NET 5 (.NET Standard 2.1)

Comment: Why is it called StringToCoTaskMemUTF8 if it works on all platforms?