# Using GhostScript 9.10 in Windows with Unicode characters in parameters

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, pinvoke, ghostscript

I want to use Ghostscript in a .NET / C# application to convert a .tiff file to PDF. 
My problem: When the file path contains non-ansi characters (e.g. Umlaute), the function

```
gsapi_init_with_args
```

fails. (With GS 8.x, it works fine!).
I found information that the behaviour was changed in 9.x, and I also found a function called

```
gsapi_init_with_argsW
```

And this function should work with .NET without any problems (see http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.printing.ghostscript.cvs/31721)

So I use the following DLLImport:

```
[DllImport(@"gsdll32.dll")]
public static extern int gsapi_init_with_argsW( IntPtr instace, int argc, string[] argv);
```

but this still does not work, I get the error:

```
Error: /undefinedfilename
in (C:\\304NDERUNGEN\\TEST.PDF)
```

The name of the file schould be

```
C:\\ÄNDERUNGEN\\TEST.PDF
```

so the umlaut "Ä" is not recognized correctly.

I´ve search the web a lot but did not found a solution.

Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: How about DllImport(@"gsdll32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode) ?

Comment: If I do that, the application hangs when calling gsapi_init_with_args, and I do not know why... I realized that gsapi_init_with_argsW does not exist in the standard ghost DLL (DLLImport will automatically fall back on gsapi_init_with_args in that case, so i didn´t got an error but used the standard gsapi_init_with_args function), so I now call gsapi_set_arg_encoding(instance, 2) directly before calling gsapi_init_with_args. This still results in the same problem described above.

Comment: Does gsapi_set_arg_encoding for unicode default to UTF8? .NET uses UTF-16, are you specifying the correct encoding?  Last resort: pass a custom-constructed array of memory pointers using pointers of memory bytes converted to UTF8?

Comment: The "2" in the call to gsapi_set_arg_encoding stands for UTF-16. If 1 would be UTF-8 and 0 would be ANSI.

Comment: It's possibly a bug in gsapi.  

Have you tried running it as a command-line process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you will need to use UTF-8 here. Make a call to `gs_set_arg_encoding` passing `GS_ARG_ENCODING_UTF8`.

Any strings that you pass to Ghostscript should be declared as `IntPtr`. To convert from a C# string to a null-terminated UTF-8 encoded string use this [function provided by Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773440/conversion-in-net-native-utf-8-managed-string/10773988#10773988):

```
public static IntPtr NativeUtf8FromString(string managedString) 
{
    int len = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(managedString);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[len + 1]; // null-terminator allocated
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(managedString, 0, managedString.Length, buffer, 0);
    IntPtr nativeUtf8 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffer.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, nativeUtf8, buffer.Length);
    return nativeUtf8;
}
```

Make sure that you remember to clean up with a call to `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`.

The overall code might look a little like this:

```
public class Ghostscript
{
    public const int GS_ARG_ENCODING_LOCAL = 0;
    public const int GS_ARG_ENCODING_UTF8 = 1;

    [DllImport("gsdll32.dll")]
    private static extern int gsapi_new_instance(out IntPtr inst, IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("gsdll32.dll")]
    private static extern int gsapi_set_arg_encoding(IntPtr inst, int encoding);

    [DllImport("gsdll32.dll")]
    private static extern int gsapi_init_with_args(IntPtr inst, int argc, IntPtr[] argv);

    [DllImport("gsdll32.dll")]
    private static extern int gsapi_exit(IntPtr inst);

    [DllImport("gsdll32.dll")]
    private static extern void gsapi_delete_instance(IntPtr inst);

    private static void checkReturnValue(int retval)
    {
        if (retval != 0)
            throw ...; // implement error handling here
    }

    public static void run(string[] argv)
    {
        IntPtr inst;
        checkReturnValue(gsapi_new_instance(out inst, IntPtr.Zero));
        try
        {
            IntPtr[] utf8argv = new IntPtr[argv.length];
            for (int i=0; i<utf8argv.Length; i++)
                utf8argv[i] = NativeUtf8FromString(argv[i]);
            try
            {
                checkReturnValue(gsapi_set_arg_encoding(inst, GS_ARG_ENCODING_UTF8));
                checkReturnValue(gsapi_init_with_args(inst, utf8argv.Length, utf8argv));
                checkReturnValue(gsapi_exit(inst));
            finally
            {
                for (int i=0; i<utf8argv.Length; i++)
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(utf8argv[i]);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            gsapi_delete_instance(inst);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Works immediatly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, I must say I am flabbergasted! I expected that you'd have to do at least a little debugging and fixing! Anyway, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: The original problem was solved, but now I get on some machines an AccessViolationException. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Nope. I guess you need a new question with all the relevant details.