# Ghostscript 9.23 and unicode filename (windows)

Tags: .net, utf-8, filenames, ghostscript

As far as I understand, ghostscript supports utf8 encoded filenames. According to the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251895/using-ghostscript-9-10-in-windows-with-unicode-characters-in-parameters?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) post, it suffices to call **gsapi_set_arg_encoding**. However, it seems that characters requiring more than 2 bytes cause error. For example, "*C:\Ä.pdf*" works fine but "*C:\€.pdf*" doesn't.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Looks like you are using Windows, and presumably you aren't using the pre-built executable ? Have you tried this with the Windows executable from the Ghostscript download site ? If that works then you know it can be done, so you could follow what thsat code does in a debugger. If it doens't then the most likely explanation would be a bug, which would more or less prepclude a workaround and would imply you should open a bug report. Note that as well as calling gs_set_arg_encoding you will have to UTF-8 encode the string of course.

Comment: @KenS What do U mean by "pre-built executable"? I'm using gsdll64.dll which is a part of gs from the the official download site...

Comment: Yes it is, but you can't run the DLL on its own, you must have an executable binary dynamically linked to it in order to be doing anything with it. That is, the code which you are writing yourself, presumably,

Comment: @KenS Tried the cmd version (gswin64c.exe). It doesn't work neither - "No such file or directory"...

Comment: Then you should probably raise a big report. Don't forget to attach a file which fails.